# Show that for any subset $S \subset V$ that the span(S) is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $S$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Here is my proof. After I show that the span(S) is a subspace of $V$, I am wondering if my proof is rigorous enough and doesn't have any holes on it. I feel okay about my reasoning, but not fully confident. Did I skip a step or assume too much in my leaps of logic?

Let the span(S) of any subset $S\subset V$ be denoted as span$(v_1, \dots v_m)$ for $v_i \in S$. First we need to check if the span(S) is a subspace of $V$.

0-vector: $0 = 0v_1 + \dots + 0v_m$ is in $S$

Closure under addition:
$$(a_1v_1 + \dots + a_mv_m) +  (c_1v_1 + \dots + c_mv_m)\\ = (a_1+c_1)v_1 + \dots + (a_m+c_m)v_m$$

Closure under scalar multiplication for $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$:
$$\lambda (a_1v_1 + \dots a_mv_m) = \lambda a_1v_1 + \dots + \lambda a_mv_m$$

Now by the given subspace properties of closure under addition and scalar multiplication, each $v_j$ is a linear combination of the span$(v_1, \dots , v_j)$.

Let $W$ be a subspace in $V$ that only contains a linear combination $x=a_1v_1 + \dots + a_mv_m$ for $v_i \in S$. Then $W$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains $S$ because every vector $v_i \in S$ can be created from the linear combination.

Comment: Your proof that it is a subspace is correct. However, your argument about it being the smallest subspace which contains $S$ is not very clear. What you have to prove is that if $W\subseteq V$ is a subspace such that $S\subseteq W$ then $span(S)\subseteq W$. And it is obviously true, because if $W$ contains all the vectors of $S$ then it also must contain all their linear combinations. (since $W$ is a vector space, hence it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication)

Comment: A minor point, that should easily be rectified: what if $S$ is not finite?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist That's totally irrelevant.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist linear combinations are always finite.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes, of course they are. That’s what I meant by “easily rectified”. My reading of the OP’s proof suggests that they assume $S$ only had $m$ elements in it, but that’s unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $\text{span}(S)$ is a subspace of $V$ is OK. ($0$ being an element need not be verified, it follows by taking the scalar $0$.) Remark that it clearly contains $S$ as well (for any $s \in S$ take the trivial $1\cdot s \in \text{span}(S)$.

The proof that it is the smallest such: suppose that $W$ is **any** linear subspace of $V$ that contains $S$. Then any member $x \in \text{span}(S)$, i.e. any $x=\alpha_1 s_1 + \ldots \alpha_n s_n$, for some finitely many $s_i \in S$ and scalars $\alpha_i$, is in $W$ as all $s_i$ are ($S \subseteq W$ by assumption, and $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication and addition, being a subspace), so $\text{span}(S) \subseteq W$. This holds for any such $S$ and that is the *definition* of being the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains $S$.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about proving that two sets are equal. For such problem, I would suggest to name the two sets. In your case, let's say $S_1 = \text{span} (S)$ and $S_2$ the smallest linear subspace containing $S$.

Then to prove that two sets are equal, a usual way is to prove that $S_1 \subseteq S_2$ and $S_2 \subseteq S_1$ by presenting the proofs for both inclusion.

You proved in the first part that $\text{span}(S)$ is a subspace and this indeed implies that $S_2 \subseteq S_1$.

Now you have to prove that $S_1 \subseteq S_2$.

To prove that it is sufficient to proof that any subspace containing $S$ contains $\text{span}(S)$. Take a subspace $S \subseteq S^\prime$ and $s \in \text{span}(S)$. By definition, it exists $s_1, \dots, s_n \in S$ and $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb K$ such that $s=\lambda_1 s_1+ \dots \lambda_n s_n$. And as $S^\prime$ is a subspace, it contains $s$. Allowing to reach the desired conclusion.

Comment: add some scalars in the last part too. "proves" should be "proofs". Show $S \subseteq \text{span}(S)$ to prove the first inclusion.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Indeed missing the scalars. And thank you to let me improve my English!